# A simple question about LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml, namespaces

```
<root xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"
      xmlns:f="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture">

<h:table>
  <h:tr>
    <h:td>Apples</h:td>
    <h:td>Bananas</h:td>
  </h:tr>
</h:table>

<f:table>
  <f:name>African Coffee Table</f:name>
  <f:width>80</f:width>
  <f:length>120</f:length>
</f:table>

</root>
```

I am trying to practice LinqToXml but i can't figure out what i wanted.Simply how can i query table elements which has h or f namespace ? 
This was what i tried .Also i tried different ones but didn't work.

```
var query = from item in XDocument.Parse(xml).Elements(ns + "table")
            select item;
```

Comment: xml is that xml string and ns is XNameSpace which is "f" or "h"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This won't work because you're missing the `root` element from your query. This would work:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3schools.com/furniture";
var query = XDocument.Parse(xml).Element("root").Elements(ns + "table");
```

Now if the problem is that you want to find *all* "table" elements *regardless* of the namespace, you'd need something like this:

```
var query = XDocument.Parse(xml)
                     .Element("root")
                     .Elements()
                     .Where(element => element.Name.LocalName == "table");
```

(EDIT: As noted, you could use `XDocument.Root` to get to the root element if you want to. The important point is that trying to get to the `table` element directly from the document node itself won't work.)

Comment: I was doing XNamespace ns ="f"; but why this is wrong ? By the way i prefer root instead of Element("root").

Comment: @Freshblood: "f" is just the label for the namespace within the XML; the real "value" of the namespace is the URL associated with it. And yes, you could use XDocument.Root if you want to - or just call XElement.Parse instead.

Answer (score 2):

Namespace prefixes are not guaranteed to be a particular letter or string.  The best approach would be to search by the qualified namespace.

*This would get all direct child nodes of `XElement xml` where the namespace is `uri:namespace`...*

```
var selectedByNamespace = from element in xml.Elements()
                          where element.Name.NamespaceName == "uri:namespace"
                          select element;
```

*Another option would be to select the elements based on the fully qualified name.*

```
var ns = "{uri:namespace}";
var selectedElements = xml.Elements(ns + "table");
```